# pagination with search result

Tags: php, pagination

I am using pagination with my script. But even it has few search cafeterias. And my pagination is also not working because of that search criteria. I want to display all the records 1st and then if the search criteria given it has to display according to that. Then only my pagination works.

But i am not getting how to do

here is my script which is to display records from database with pagination

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])){ $page=$_GET['page']; } else { $page=1; }
$start_page=($page-1)*5;

`$sql="query";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{


    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $product = $_POST['product'];


if(isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['company']!='') && ($_POST['product']!=''))
{
$sql= "My query goes here";
}

elseif(isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['company']!=''))
{
$sql= "My query goes here";
}   
elseif(isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST['product']!=''))
{
$sql= "My query goes here";
}   

elseif(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$sql= "My query goes here";

}
}
$sql1 = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
//Display
?>
<div class="w-box w-box-blue">
<div class="w-box-header">
   </div>
<div class="w-box-content"> 

    <table id="dt_hScroll" class="table table-striped">
                        <thead><tr>
                        <th>Order ID</th>
                        <th>Company</th>
                        <th>Reference</th>
                        <th>Total Value</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <?php
                        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
{

    //Display
}
    ?>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
 <?php
 //PAGINATION SCRIPT

$sql1="select COUNT(order_id) from orders";
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql1);

$row1 = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result);
$total_records = $row1[0];
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 5);

  if ($page > $total_pages) {
   // set current page to last page
   $page = $total_pages;
} // end if
// if current page is less than first page...
if ($page < 1) {
   // set current page to first page
   $page = 1;
} // end if
$range=4;
            echo "<div style='float:left; width:200px;text-align:center; margin-left:40%;'>";
           // echo "<a href='view_student.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";

            if ($page > 1) {
   // show << link to go back to page 1
   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=1'>First</a> ";
   // get previous page num
   $prevpage = $page - 1;
   // show < link to go back to 1 page
   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$prevpage'>Previous</a> ";
} // end if 

// loop to show links to range of pages around current page
for ($x = ($page - $range); $x < (($page + $range) + 1); $x++) {
   // if it's a valid page number...
   if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $total_pages)) {
      // if we're on current page...
      if ($x == $page) {
         // 'highlight' it but don't make a link
         echo " [<b>$x</b>] ";
      // if not current page...
      } else {
         // make it a link
         echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$x'>$x</a> ";
      } // end else

   } // end if
} // end for

// if not on last page, show forward and last page links        
if ($page != $total_pages) {
   // get next page
   $nextpage = $page + 1;
    // echo forward link for next page
   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$nextpage'>Next</a> ";
   // echo forward link for lastpage
   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$total_pages'>Last</a> ";
} // end if

            echo "</div>";

?>
```

Comment: What do you expect? Someone doing the coding for you?

Comment: @ThomasKilian: I just want to know where i made mistakes

Comment: Then please state what you see and what you expect (by example).

Comment: Your count should also consider your search filter.

Comment: I have edited my code, if i display all the records before the `$_POST[;submit']`, it doesn't take search criteria. And pagination also doesn't work. It shows all the age numbers like 1, 2, but after clicking same records getting displayed and also `page limit` also  not working

Answer (score 0):

Try using some kind of query builder, that would make your task easier.
All popular frameworks have that kind of tool. It would be much easier to build *count* query for pagination.
You may look here for example http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html